# parallax/ken burns effect without scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Ok so I am applying a parallax/ken burns effect on an image but I am not convinced the method I am using to do this is that good. It works well on webkit browsers, but is not very smooth on firefox and does not work at all in IE

It's pretty simple I have a background image in a div and on window load I apply a class called pan that changes the background position.

Would anyone have any ideas for a way of achieving this effect that would be SMOOTH and pan nicely.

Here is the site http://dev.touch-akl.com/xmas/

```
#banner{
  background-size: 100%;  
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0 0;
  padding-top:35.15625%;
  -o-transition-duration: 10s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 10s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 10s;      
  }
```

At one point I even had a small scale on the .pan class that looked great in chrome but was even worse on firefox

```
  #banner.pan{
    background-position:0 160%;   
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the free plugin for the ken burn effect you can download it

here is the [demo](http://www.subchild.com/slideshowify/)

Comment: Thanks, That plugin looks good. Do you think that it is a bit of an overkill to use 2 plugins (jquery.transit & slideshowify) to do this effect on 1 image? What I liked about the way I was doing it is that it is really lightweight.

Not saying the plugin is bad, just looking for an opinion :-)

Comment: i think it will be better to use one plugin i dont suggest two plugin for same slider

Comment: The ken burn plugin says you need to include both for it to work?